# Java EE Application in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jpa, ear

I'm developing a web service which will be exposed to our vendors. This web service gets requests from vendors and saves them in a database.

To develop it I'm creating three projects in Eclipse:

- Enterprise Application Project
- Webservice Project
- EJB Project

Now my question is, should I create a JPA project for the entities or should I create those entities in the EJB Project? These entities will be used by service classes in the EJB Project.

Comment: You can create a domain project where you define all your domain model as POLOs and declare JPA annotations on them.  You can refer this project from EJB so that they are accessible.

Comment: this can be done now and we can add JPA project in build path of EJB Project. i want to know preferred way and what advantage we get by separating model? if we add models in EJB Project it works fine.

Comment: Modularity.  If you want to any changes to domain objects only without disturbing services, then you can upgrade domain objects jar only.  And also if you want to reuse domain objects with some other projects you can do so.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need create new project as "EJB-api" ("EJB-client") and apply Transfer Object Pattern ([link](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/TransferObject.html)).
Then 
EJB Project: DAO impl, BL impl, entities 
EJB-client(as jar library): DAO api, BL api, transfer objcets